# Having startup messages on virtual tty (monitor) AND serial console

Tags: linux, debian, serial, debian-buster

I have enabled serial console over null-modem cable in Debian 10 like this:

`/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=ttyS0,115200n8"
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

then `systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service`.

That was all there was to it. However, while now I can see all the startup messages over serial (initial kernel messages and `systemctl` service start messages), nothing is displayed on monitor (virtual tty) until login prompt appears.

Is it possible to have those startup messages displayed on **both** monitor and over serial connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, specify `console=` twice in the kernel command line.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8"
```